# Trying to identify compilation option according to the loaded modules

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have 2 projects that use the same control. One of them works on Windows8, and the other does not.
I tried to make both projects use the same compilation options, yet they do not load the same modules.

Is there something common to the following DLLs, so I can spot what compilation option did I miss?

I compile both projects on VisualStudio 2010.

Most of the DLLs are common to both projects, Only the following are different
[list taken from Visual Studio, when the application is running, Use Debug | Windows | Modules]

The working project contains the following:

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **clbcatq.dll**            2001.12.4414.700                4/14/2008 2:09 AM

  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **comres.dll**          2001.12.4414.700                4/14/2008 2:09 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **ddraw.dll**           5.03.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0845)       4/14/2008 2:09 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **ddrawex.dll**         5.03.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0845)       4/14/2008 2:09 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **dsound.dll**          5.3.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0845)        4/14/2008 2:10 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **midimap.dll**         5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0845)        4/14/2008 2:10 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **msacm32.dll**         5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0845)        4/14/2008 2:11 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **msacm32.drv**         5.1.2600.0 (xpclient.010817-1148)       8/18/2001 7:33 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **mscms.dll**           5.1.2600.5627 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.080624-1245)    6/24/2008 6:43 PM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **schannel.dll**        5.1.2600.6239 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.120601-1620)    6/4/2012 6:32 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **wdmaud.drv**          5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2108)        4/14/2008 2:11 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **winmm.dll**           5.1.2600.6160 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.111014-1624)    10/14/2011 4:47 PM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **winspool.drv**        5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0852)        4/14/2008 2:11 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **ws2_32.dll**          5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0852)        4/14/2008 2:12 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **ws2help.dll**         5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0852)        4/14/2008 2:12 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **comdlg32.dll**        6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)       4/14/2008 2:09 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **mlang.dll**           6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)       4/14/2008 2:10 AM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **urlmon.dll**          6.00.2900.6347 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.130205-1023)   2/6/2013 12:48 PM
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **wininet.dll**         6.00.2900.6347 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.130205-1023)   2/6/2013 12:48 PM

While the project that does not work, contains the following:

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\ **shfolder.dll**    6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)       4/14/2008 2:10 AM

Is there something common to these DLLs, so I can spot what compilation option did I miss?

This is the exception :

```
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an
incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) at   
control__lib.control__wrapper.FPC_LoadOCXCodeFromMemory
                               (UInt32 pData, UInt32 dwSize) at 
control__lib.AxCode..ctor(Stream StreamWithOCXCode) at 
my.mcInit() at 
my.Main()
```

Comment: I compile on XP. when running on windows 8, I get an exception from the control constructor, but the author of the control could not find the reason.

Comment: The stack trace is in the control constructor. the author of the control could not find the reason. When I run the author demo, all works well. I just try to find what is the difference between the way he builds (and run) his project [upgraded from VS 2005 to VS 2010] and the way I compile my project [upgraded from VS 2003 to 2008 to VS 2010].

Comment: Please give us the exception details and the stack trace - they are required to help.

Comment: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with 
 an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at control__lib.control__wrapper.FPC_LoadOCXCodeFromMemory(UInt32 pData, UInt32 dwSize)
   at control__lib.AxCode..ctor(Stream StreamWithOCXCode)
   at my.mcInit()  
   at my.Main()

Comment: + project compiled for x86, tested on Windows 8 32-bit.

Comment: Can you also give the line of code where the exception is triggered?  It seems like a 32/64bit conflict.  Are any of the dependencies in the project compiled for "AnyCPU"?

Comment: The exception is triggered at the control constructor

Comment: You've said that already.  It also does not answer the question.

Comment: I do not have access to the control source code :( . It seems that most of these DLLs relates to XP SP3, I wonder why the DLLs are not included in my project

Comment: You did not write this control?? If it isn't your source code that is breaking then this is **not** a programming question - it is something you should submit to the developer as a bug report.  If the component came with an installer you may need to wrap it into your own application's installer to ensure that the required libraries get installed and registered.

Comment: The demo project of the control does work, but when I try to use this control in my project - it does not, and the difference I found is these DLLs that are included when running demo project, and not included when running my project. I thought it might be a property of the compilation that I missed, so I asked what is common to these DLLs, so I can identify the compilation(?) property I missed.

Comment: Tell us what the control is - what is its name and where did it come from?  This should have been the first thing you included.